# Can't upload (FTP) PHP file containing base64_decode()?

Tags: php, security, ftp

I have a plain server running CentOS 7.2 and Virtualmin, with FTP access via ProFTPD 1.3.5, and when I try to upload a PHP file containing the string `base64_decode` the transfer hangs until time-out. I have verified by editing the function out, and the exact same file uploads near-instantly. Put the function back in and the upload times-out. I can even just remove the '64' from the function name and the file uploads successfully.

So it appears to be some kind of security, but from where? Surely someone has seen this before? Or is my diagnosis completely off?

Comment: We can't say anything here...There is nothing that _should_ block such a file transfer. If that happens, then there must be some reason. But without details like log file entries or similar there is nothing we can say except: if you say it is blocked, then apparently it is blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not related to FTP, but to some Intrusion Detection System (IDS) which tries to block transfer of suspicious files. This IDS might run at the host or somewhere in the network.

Comment: Things got weirder when I couldn't even access this post from Chrome... turns out my fancy Asus RT-AC68U router has a setting labelled _Vulnerability Protection_ which was blocking anything containing the aforementioned string. You learn something everyday, thanks for the pointer Steffen!

Answer (score 0):

It is blocked to prevent malicious code tranfer.

To circumvent this:

```
sed 's/base64_decode/QQQQQ_decode/g' YOUR_FILE > NEW_FILE
```

transfer NEW_FILE via FTP

On the target computer:

```
sed 's/QQQQQ_decode/base64_decode/g' NEW_FILE > YOUR_FILE
```